# How to enable `Github Copilot` typing `Tab` to auto completes in markdown files?

Tags: visual-studio-code, github-copilot

I can get some suggestions by copilot in `.md` files, But when I keydowned `Tab`, it only added a space, not autocompletes the suggestion, What should I do can autocomplete the suggestion?

[image]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To enable suggestions for GitHub Copilot with a <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, follow the steps below.

1. Open the file `keybindings.json` in Visual Studio Code. This can be done by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, and typing *Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)*.
2. In `keybindings.json`, add the following.

   ```json
   [
     {
       "key": "tab",
       "command": "editor.action.inlineSuggest.commit",
       "when": "textInputFocus && inlineSuggestionHasIndentationLessThanTabSize && inlineSuggestionVisible && !editorTabMovesFocus"     
     }
   ]
   ```

This should now enable you to accept suggestions in Markdown using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key!

*Note: Make sure to restart VS Code after this.*

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried a while, `editor.action.inlineSuggestion.commit` is a invalid command, but `editor.action.inlineSuggest.commit` is a valid command, base on your code, I wrote a seems correct keybinds

Comments cnat't add block code, so I edited my question for adding keybinds

Thanks again

Comment: ```json
 {
  "key": "tab",
  "command": "editor.action.inlineSuggest.commit",
  "when": "textInputFocus && inlineSuggestionHasIndentationLessThanTabSize && inlineSuggestionVisible && !editorTabMovesFocus"
 },
```

Comment: You are a god. I looked for 1 full day on how to resolve this junk and only you gave me a working solution. Thank you so much, truly.

Comment: Do not forget to restart your VS code after this.

Answer (score 2):

Solution-

For me Right arrow key works to accept suggestion. Try Right arrow key.